# cells/rows are inserted under the first column

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on a real-time timetable for a school, for that I've an admin panel with a side "User verwalten" (manage users) where I manage the rights and permissions of the individual users. I want to create a table with the name and checkbox where you can mark the rights with a cross.
The data for this(all users and there permissions) are located on a webserver.

**The Problem:**
Now I have added the table-header and I want to add the users. But now with the table-header everything gets added in the first column and I dont know why. When I debugged, it is found that the cells are added in the right row but if I add the row it looks like this:
[image]

But i want it to look like this **but with** a table-header:
[image]

Here is the code for createTable()

```
function createTable(json){
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    var oldBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
                    var body = document.createElement('tbody');
                    //if i add this header everything gets desroyed
                    //var header = document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = '<tr><th class="header"><h3>Name</h3></th><th class="header"><h3>Schüler verwalten</h3></th><th class="header"><h3>Benutzer verwalten</h3></th><th class="header"><h3>History anschauen</h3></th><th class="header"><h3>Home verwalten</h3></th></tr>';

                    for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
                            var row = addRow(obj[j]);
                            row.classList.add('row');
                            //table.appendChild(body);
                    }
                }
```

code foraddRow()

```
function addRow(val) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    if(i==0){
                        var name = val.substr(0,(val.length)-9);
                        addCell(tr, null,name);
                    }else{
                        var rest = val.substr((val.length)-9, val.length);
                        var values = rest.split(";");
                        addCell(tr, values[i], name);
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                }

            return tr;
            }
```

code for addCell()

```
function addCell(tr, val, name) {

                var name;
                var cell = document.createElement('input');
                var value = "get";
                if(val == null){
                    cell.classList.add("name")
                    cell.value = name;
                    cell.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
                                        cell.classList.remove('cell');
                                        cell.classList.add('selected');
                                        clearSelection();
                                    });
                }else if(val == 0){
                    cell.classList.add('checkbox');
                    cell.type = "checkbox";
                    cell.checked = false;
                    cell.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
                        value += getString();
                        getData(value);
                    });

                }else if(val == 1){
                    cell.classList.add('checkbox');
                    cell.type = "checkbox";
                    cell.checked = true;
                    cell.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
                        value += getString();

                        getData(value);
                    });

                }
                tr.appendChild(cell);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set a `newStartIndex` var.

Something like this is what I did. (If I understand correctly) 
I realize this might not be exactly what you are asking but perhaps it points you in the right direction.

```
var ucfIndex = 2;
const ucfSelectedRowIndex = rows.indexOf(feedbackCandidates[x]) + ucfIndex;

var sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4' });
authorize(function () {
var request = {
    spreadsheetId: 'yourSheetId',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    resource: {

        "data": [
            {
                "range": "N" + ucfSelectedRowIndex,
                "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
                "values": [
                    [
                        true
                    ],
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    auth,
};

sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate(request, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.info(response);
        console.log("Col Values updated");
    };
});

});
```

Comment: the problem is not in the request it appears when i assemble the table

Comment: check your `majorDimension": "COLUMNS",` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Code for Add row

var table = document.getElementById("tbl");

```
    for (var i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length; i++) {

        var row = "";

        for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {

            row += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
            row += " | ";
        }

        alert(row);
    }
```